# jQuery closest() method targets the current element instead of its closest element

Tags: jquery

I read an answer to a question that says that the `closest()` method only works on parent elements. So I did an example that shows three `<ul>` elements with `<li>` children. I applied a jQuery code on the second `<ul>` to see if the `closest()` method targets the previous closest element or the next closest element; I was surprised that it targeted the current element instead, which is the second `<ul>`.

HTML

```
<ul class="ul-1">
  <li>UL 1 - Li 1</li>
  <li>UL 1 - Li 2</li>
  <li>UL 1 - Li 3</li>
  <li>UL 1 - Li 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul-2">
  <li>UL 2 - Li 1</li>
  <li>UL 2 - Li 2</li>
  <li>UL 2 - Li 3</li>
  <li>UL 2 - Li 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ul-3">
  <li>UL 3 - Li 1</li>
  <li>UL 3 - Li 2</li>
  <li>UL 3 - Li 3</li>
  <li>UL 3 - Li 4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.ul-2').closest('ul').css('background','red');
```

Am I using the `closest()` method wrong?

Comment: The documentation is extremely clear on what [Clostest Actually does:](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - *For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree*.  I'm not sure why this is even a question.  (since `.ul-2` is a `ul` jquery selects the same element)

Comment: This should have been very easy to sort out by reading the api docs. You are expected to do reasonable research before asking here

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `.siblings` or `.prev`:

```
$('.ul-2').prev('ul').css('background','red');
```

- `.closest` - Parent.
- `.prev` - Previous Sibling.
- `.next` - Next Sibling.